# In Angular, should we call validation functions inside .controller.js or in .html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, performance, model-view-controller

I have a small Angular question for you.

Let's say I have a `.html` code that looks like this:

`<div>
     <span>{{billingController.amount}}</span>
</div>`

In my controller file I initialize the value like this:

`vm.billingController.amount = parseAmount(vm.billingController.amount );`

To sum up: every variable I have is initialized like this so that if the values are `null` / `undefined` / empty I apply some logic to it with the `parseAmount` function, so that the default value is something I want my way.

Is there any performance gains relatively to invoke the same function like this:

`<div>
     <span>{{billingController.parseAmount(billingController.amount)}}</span>
</div>`

Will having the same function directly into the `.html` fire it multiple times? Is there any performance issues using the second option?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these two are way different things

when you doing it in js, its assigning the value back

```
    vm.billingController.amount = parseAmount(vm.billingController.amount );
```

where as in html its just a display

```
<div>
     <span>{{billingController.parseAmount(billingController.amount)}}</span>
</div>
```

About preference: generally one should prefer to have custom logic in js and not html. Use html for display only (as far as possible), `expression sandboxes` are anyway discouraged

Answer (score 1):

Correct approach is to define scope and model in angular js and use that in html.Unlike the other MVC frameworks, AngularJS doesn’t have specific classes or functions to create model objects. Instead, AngularJS extended the raw JavaScript objects with custom methods and properties. These objects, also known as scope in AngularJS terms, work as a glue between the view and other parts ( directives, controllers and services ) inside the AngularJS application.

With the ng-model directive you can bind the value of an input field to a variable created in AngularJS.

Example:

```
 <div>
     <span>Amount: ng-model="amount"  ng-bind="amount"</span>
</div>
        <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
       var amount=getAmount();
        $scope.amount= parseAmount(amount);
         //you need to put the logic inside getamount()
    });
    </script>
```